# MSSQL testcontainer tests stuck in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

I'm trying to run unit and integration tests on Bitbucket CICD.
We are using `SpringBoot 3.1.5` with `Testcontainers 1.19.3`.
Locally, all tests pass both from IntelliJ and from cmd line.

Base integration test setup using MSSQL as database and RabbitMQ is:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)
public class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    static final MSSQLServerContainer<?> SQLSERVER_CONTAINER;
    static final RabbitMQContainer rabbitmq;

    static {
        rabbitmq = new RabbitMQContainer(DockerImageName.parse("rabbitmq:3.7.25-management-alpine"));
        rabbitmq.start();

        SQLSERVER_CONTAINER = new MSSQLServerContainer<>(
            "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
            .withStartupCheckStrategy(new MinimumDurationRunningStartupCheckStrategy(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
            .withStartupTimeoutSeconds(240)
            .acceptLicense();
        SQLSERVER_CONTAINER.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void overridePropertiesInternal(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.host", rabbitmq::getHost);
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.port", rabbitmq::getAmqpPort);
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.username", rabbitmq::getAdminUsername);
        registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.password", rabbitmq::getAdminPassword);

        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", SQLSERVER_CONTAINER::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", SQLSERVER_CONTAINER::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", SQLSERVER_CONTAINER::getPassword);
    }
```

Since I had issues with troubleshooting errors on bitbucket, this is the first part of latest version of my bitbucket-pipelines file:

```
image: maven:3.9.5-amazoncorretto-21

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &install
        name: 'Install MVN packages'
        script:
          - mvn install -DskipTests
    - step: &test
        name: 'Build and Test'
        size: 2x
        script:
          - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
          - mvn clean verify
        services:
          - docker
```

So, having all this together, once pipeline is run and tests start with execution, pipeline gets stuck on the first test that uses MSSQL container. End of the log looks like this:

```
13:58:30.679 [main] INFO tc.mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest -- Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:32772;encrypt=false)


: The following 1 profile is active: "test"

2023-11-28T13:58:33.636Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2023-11-28T13:58:33.902Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 255 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.

2023-11-28T13:58:35.502Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.implementation.jdbc.AzureJdbcAutoConfiguration' of type [com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.implementation.jdbc.AzureJdbcAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2023-11-28T13:58:35.505Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'springTokenCredentialProviderContextProvider' of type [com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.implementation.jdbc.SpringTokenCredentialProviderContextProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2023-11-28T13:58:36.124Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)

2023-11-28T13:58:36.164Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2023-11-28T13:58:36.164Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]

2023-11-28T13:58:36.323Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2023-11-28T13:58:36.324Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4295 ms

Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts

2023-11-28T13:58:36.727Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2023-11-28T13:59:00.298Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: d667bb64-9947-4f1b-887b-fec59b58d465

2023-11-28T13:59:00.301Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2023-11-28T13:59:05.012Z  INFO 303 --- [           main] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to dbo
```

Sometimes it gets stuck on `liquibase` log entry, sometimes few entries above it when `HikariCP` is starting.
I'm not sure whether this is a Docker image problem, Testcontainers issue, infra issue... How can I troubleshoot this, any ideas?